# Will the mobile app auto register device again after delete contact in MC

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I have updated the new version of mobile app with Contact Key updated and the user is starting upgrade the app. I discovered that when the app is updated the contact key also not changed.

Is there any way I can update contact key when user update mobile app?

What if I delete all the contact, will the contact key be registered again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When users start updating the App and gets registered with the Contact Key a new Contact will get created (or updated if Contact Key already exists). The device will then be tied to this new Contact. The old contact that got created without Contact Key will be orphaned.

> **Orphaned Contacts**
>
> **What is an orphaned contact?**
>
> An orphaned contact is a contact that is no longer targetable by the
>   marketer due to the contact becoming disassociated with any known
>   devices in the Marketing Cloud.
>
> **Common causes of orphaned contacts**
>
> Initializing the SDK without setting the
>   sfmc_setDelayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet flag to true in an app
>   that will eventually associate the device users with a known
>   identifier.
>
> 1. List item The first launch of the app the SDK will send a registration to the Marketing Cloud. This will be done before it would
>      be possible for the customer to set a contact key.
> 2. Upon receiving a registration payload without a contact key, the
>      Marketing Cloud will generate one for the device. (eg. abc123)
> 3. At a point in the future (let’s say once the user logs into their
>      account in the application) the app sets the known contact key in
>      the registration.
> 4. The device will now send a new registration payload to the Marketing
>      Cloud, a new contact will be created and the device will become
>      associated with the new contact.

[Registration Updates Via Contact Key, Attributes, and Tags](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/sdk-implementation/user-data.html)

You then need to decide what to do with your orphaned contacts. Most likely you would want to delete these.